# iPhone tableview edit delete and add button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I need to make a selection screen pop up after a long press on a tableview.
In this selection screen I need 3 options:

- 1 for editing the long pressed cell
- 1 for deleting the cell
- 1 for adding a new cell.

How can I do this?

I know how to do something when a cell is clicked, but I don't know how I can edit/delete a cell.

Just one more small question:
When this cell has been edited and the application terminates, I need to save all the cells to a file called `exercises`.
This file already contains the array/cell of cells that the app started with so I need to delete all the content and then write it again.

Comment: Your question would more easy to understand if you used some punctuation such as commas. It's hard on the brain to read a stream of text without pauses...

Comment: @occulus I agree. I didn't even read the question, just because of this.

Comment: sry that im not that good at english :-(

Comment: okay so have been searching around for a few hours.

Comment: okay so have been searching around for a few hours.

and i fund this guide http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-DeleteandaddrowfromTableView.html

with i have been look at and have goth it working now :-) the delete arrange and add button 

just one more question i i wan't a popup like actionsheet but where i can enter a name what due i have to looke for then??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tableview delegate protocol has standard methods for handling the editing of the tableview. See the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).

If you are saving the data from the table in an array, you can overwrite the existing file just by calling `-[NSArray writeToFile:]` and providing the same path.

Comment: hey so i have been looke at the table view programming guide for IOS alsov before i startet this post but i can't find the right why to use this i can see that there is  setEditing:animated: but i don't know who i can use this :-( and i can't find a why to make this selection pop up screen 

sry for my english

Comment: okay so have been searching around for some time .

and i fund this guide http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-DeleteandaddrowfromTableView.html

with i have been look at and have goth it working now :-) the delete arrange and add button 

just one more question i i wan't a popup like actionsheet but where i can enter a name what due i have to looke for then??

Comment: You don't want to use a popup to enter text with because it is to difficult to position and to difficult for the user to type into. Instead, push a second view that lets you edit text. Look at how the Contact or Preferences apps handles things. Those are good design examples.

Comment: okay ty for the answere have been looking on it for a wile now and have gotten createt so the app button makes this new view and lets the user enter the data but how can i make it public so it can be accesed from the othere files?? i know that i just can use INHERITANCE but that gives me a some problem becuse i only wan't the varibals from the files what will be the why to due this??

i cut make this so when the view is getting unloadet it's wirth to the file and then the new view loads from the file but i thing this will cost much more memory